# How can i put async Task<List<>> into a BindableCollection<>

Tags: c#, wpf

How can i await for a **Task** and return its **result** and putting the results of the **Task** into a **BindableCollection**.
Having trouble with the syntax for (return await Task.Run()) and putting it into a BindableCollection.
Basically what iam trying todo is to await for the result of the method, return it and put it into a BindableCollection in ViewModel and binding to the ItemsControl.
I looked up for some examples in multiple threads, unfortuneatly none of the threads contains anything about BindableCollection.
I can only guess that i have to Convert somehow the Generic List to IEnumerable, though i have no clue how.

```
public class DataAccess : Conductor<object>
{
    public async Task<List<DataModel>> Starter(IProgress<ProgressReportModel> progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        List<DataModel> output = new List<DataModel>();

        //What i tried so far
        return await ScannerAsync(progress, cancellationToken);
        List<GameDataModel>> output = await ScannerAsync(progress, cancellationToken);
    }

    private static async Task<List<DataModel>> ScannerAsync(IProgress<ProgressReportModel> progress, CancellationToken cs)
    {
         await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Do Stuff

        }).ConfigureAwait(true);

         await Task.Run(() =>
        { 
            Do Stuff and return output.
        }).ConfigureAwait(true);
    }
}

public class ViewModel : Conductor<object>
{
   private BindableCollection<DataModel> Data { get; set; }
   private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
   private Progress<ProgressReportModel> progress = new Progress<ProgressReportModel>();

   public void StartScan()
   {
      DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
      Data = new BindableCollection<DataModel>(da.Starter(progress, cts.Token));
      // ERROR: Cannot Convert from Tasks.Task to Generic.IEnumerable
   }
}
```

Comment: Your code tries to convert the Task to BindableCollection<DataModel>, you'd want to convert the RESULT of the task instead, to do it you need to await the da.Start method:

Data = new BindableCollection<DataModel>(await da.Starter(progress, cts.Token));

You may need to tweak the signature of your StartScan method to public async Task StartScan

Comment: Thanks Alot ! i managed todo it. I didnt know that i was close to the right answer. Just had to additionally wire up the INotifyPropertyChanged and voilah.

Comment: Great! Would you mind accepting the comment as answer if I put it there? to close this question?

Comment: Yes Sure, i was looking for that tbh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code tries to convert the Task to BindableCollection, you'd want to convert the RESULT of the task instead, to do it you need to await the da.Start call:

```
Data = new BindableCollection<DataModel>(await da.Starter(progress, cts.Token));
```

You may need to tweak the signature of your StartScan method to

```
public async Task StartScan()
```